# jQuery alert onclick on element's child?

Tags: jquery

I'm using this code to display an alert on a certain element:

```
$("#resultsBox").click(function (event) {
    console.log('a');
    });
```

I want to display an alert only when you click on 'li' elements inside '#resultsBox'.

I'm trying to do it like this:

```
$("#resultsBox li").click(function (event) {
    console.log('a');
    });
```

This is the element's #resultsBox structure:

```
<div id="resultsBox">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can this be done?

Comment: What's wrong with that? It doesn't work? It should..

Comment: And? What's the problem? Looks just fine.

Comment: That should work. Perhaps you're adding the `li` elements dynamically? Or perhaps the HTML is invalid and is somehow messing up the selector?

Comment: Fiddler is expected for your problem

Comment: If its working and you want to fire event on `li` only. `add return false;`. `$("#resultsBox li").click(function (event) {
    console.log('a');return false;
});`

Comment: Your `li`s are empty how are you clicking on them?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

When you bind an event handler with `.click()` it applies to any elements that matched your selector *at that moment*, not to elements later added dynamically.

Given your div is called "resultsBox", it seems reasonable to assume you are actually adding things to it dynamically to display the results of some other operation, in which case you need to use a delegated event handler:

```
$("#resultsBox").on("click", "li", function (event) {
    console.log('a');
});
```

This syntax of the [`.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) binds a handler to "#resultsBox", but then when the click occurs jQuery checks whether it was on a child element that matches the "li" selector in the second parameter - if so it calls your function, otherwise not.

Comment: Is this valid ? You are selecting `li` and passing `li` in second arg ?

Comment: Sorry @Jashwant, you are correct, but I noticed that typo and removed it.

Comment: Yes, I'm adding them dynamically however I was running these codes just after the ajax call however for some reason nor other answer works. Anyway this works. Thanks

Comment: With your original code you'd have to put it in the Ajax _callback_ function just after adding the elements, not in code after the `$.ajax()` call.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this should work

```
$("#resultsBox").find("li").click(function(){
  alert("You clicked on li " + $(this).text());
});
```

This should work now: http://jsbin.com/ocejar/2/edit

But anyway, also your example above using `$("#resultsBox li")` should work just fine. See [here](http://jsbin.com/ocejar/4/edit). However, using `$("#resultsBox").find("li")` should be a [little faster](http://www.slideshare.net/AddyOsmani/jquery-proven-performance-tips-tricks) in terms of performances.

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't catch the click. I updated the question with the elements contents maybe that's the reason it doesn't work.

Comment: The selector in the question was `$("#resultsBox li")...` which will already looki for li elements that are descendants (not necessarily direct children) of #resultsBox. There's no `>` in the question's code.

Comment: @nnnnnn Sorry, missed that :) Seemed as if I had seen a > somewhere...anyway updated my answer now. thx

Answer (score 1):

Your code as you have it should be working: http://jsfiddle.net/GxCCb/

Its important to note that the elements you're trying to attach the event handler to must exist when the code is evaluated.  If it is added at a later time, then you must use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) (v1.7+) or [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) (< 1.7), which is used for event delegation and allows the elements to be referenced if they are added later..

Using **on()**:

```
$("#resultsBox").on('click', 'li', function (event) {
    alert(this.innerHTML);
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7Lz2Y/

Using **delegate()**:

```
$("#resultsBox").delegate('li', 'click', function (event) {
    alert(this.innerHTML);
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XwYs5/

However, there are plenty of other methods for attaching the event handler for elements that exist prior:

```
$("#resultsBox").find('li').click(function (event) {
    alert(this.innerHTML);
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/74Q7p/

```
$("#resultsBox ul > li").click(function (event) {
    alert(this.innerHTML);
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a28U5/

Comment: You're correct about the elements needing to exist when that code runs, but then the two alternative methods you show both have that same problem.

Comment: @nnnnnn - Good point, I have added an example using `on()` and `delegate()` and updated my answer for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
$("#resultsBox ul li").click(function (event) {
    console.log('a');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#resultsBox").click(function (event) {
    if(event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "li"){
         console.log('a');
    }
});
```

This will work for the dynamically added li elements.

Comment: Yes it is, while binding events with javascript, event.target is not identified in Internet Explorer. It searches for event.srcElement. That has been handled in jQuery perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE after question edit:

```
<div id="resultsBox">
  <ul id="myList">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>


$("#myList > li").click(function (event) {

        console.log('a');

        });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sX2BF/)

Comment: This wont work. `li` is not direct descendant of `#resultsBox`

Comment: Agree but this question was added before the question was edited and it was said that `click on 'li' elements inside '#resultsBox'`

Comment: @Jashwant you are pretty smart.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#resultsBox").find('li').click(function (event) {
    alert($(this).text());
    });
```